# Error in Python program when multiplying integers by fractions and decimals

Tags: python, math, equation

I tried to make a short program that works out the famous Drake equation. I got it to accept integer inputs, decimal inputs, and fractional inputs. However, I get this error when the program attempts to multiply them (right after I input all necessary values the error happens):

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "C:/Users/Family/Desktop/Programming/Python Files/1/DrakeEquation1.py", line 24, in <module>
    calc() #cal calc to execute it
  File "C:/Users/Family/Desktop/Programming/Python Files/1/DrakeEquation1.py", line 17, in calc
    calc = r*fp*ne*fl*fi*fc*l
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

My code is as follows:

```
def intro():
    print('This program will evaluate the Drake equation with your values')

def calc():
    print('What is the average rate of star formation in the galaxy?')
    r = input()
    print('What fraction the stars have planets?')
    fp = input()
    ne = int(input('What is the average number of life supporting planets (per     star)?'))
    print('What fraction of these panets actually develop life')
    fl = input()
    print('What fraction of them will develop intelligent life')
    fi = input()
    print('What fraction of these civilizations have developed detectable technology?')
    fc = input()
    l = int(input('How long will these civilizations release detectable signals?'))
    calc = r*fp*ne*fl*fi*fc*l

    print('My estimate of the number of detectable civilizations is ' + calc + ' .')


if __name__=="__main__":
    intro() #cal intro to execute it 
    calc() #cal calc to execute it
```

What do I need to change in order to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert your input values to floats.

```
r = float(input())
```

(Note: in Python versions less than 3, use `raw_input` instead of `input`.)

And so on for the other variables. Otherwise you're attempting to multiply a string by a string.

Edit: as others have pointed out, `calc` additionally cannot be concatenated to the surrounding strings using the `+` operator. Use string substitution for that:

```
print('My estimate of the number of detectable civilizations is %s.' % calc)
```

Comment: Using raw_input()) in line 6 yields the following error: r = float(raw_input())
NameError: global name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: I see, you must be using Python 3. Python 3 [renamed](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html) `raw_input` to `input`; I've updated my code above.

Comment: Okay, that works. The only problem left is that if I enter a fraction (e.x. '2/3') for a question asking for a fraction I get this error:ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2/3' ; however the program works perfectly if I only use integers and decimals.

Comment: If you need fractions to be converted to floats, you might be better off using the old behavior of `input`, which can be simulated in Python 3 via `eval(input())`. Do note that using `eval` is generally discouraged, though.

Comment: All right, I'll make the necessary changes. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Instead of eval, you should try using `split()`, `int()` and `fraction.Fraction()`.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the answers asserting that the problem's with not casting the output of `input` to the correct type.  The real problem is

1. Not properly validating the input to the program, and
2. Trying to concatenate a str with a number on this line:

   ```
   print('My estimate of th..." + calc + ' .')
   ```

Your program runs fine for me given integers, floats and fractional values as input.  Given `'1'` and `'1'` (quoted) as the first two inputs, it returns the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You have converted some values into appropriate types for arithmetic but not the others.  The real values should be passed to `float()` and the ratios should be parsed and computed (or use the [`Fraction`](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) type, or force your user to input a real).  An example of the latter is posted below:

```
print('What is the average rate of star formation in the galaxy?')
r = float(input())
print('What fraction the stars have planets?')
fp = float(input())
ne = int(input('What is the average number of life supporting planets (per star)?'))
print('What fraction of these panets actually develop life')
fl = float(input())
```

Comment: Using the newly revised code (everything is a float) I get this error upon entering the first fraction: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Family/Desktop/Programming/Python Files/1/DrakeEquation1.py", line 24, in <module>
    calc() #cal calc to execute it
  File "C:/Users/Family/Desktop/Programming/Python Files/1/DrakeEquation1.py", line 8, in calc
    fp = float(input())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2/3'

Comment: Right, keep in mind that the example posted accepts reals only.

Answer (score 0):

> input([prompt]) -> value
>
> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).

So, I suggest you to use `raw_input` to avoid potential errors.